# css letter spacing doesn't work when the page was rendered by document.write

Tags: css, document.write, letter-spacing

Below code works as I expected. Every thing is perfectly styling.

```
<style>
   .letter-spacing{
      width: 400px;
      background: red;
      text-align: center;
      letter-spacing: 20px;
    }
</style>

<div class="letter-spacing">
   <img src="icon1.png">
   <img src="icon2.png">
</div>
```

[image: result with letter-spacing]

However, if I render the "div" using document.write, "letter-spacing: 20px;" doesn't work. The interesting thing is red background and center alignment still work.

```
<style>
   .letter-spacing{
      width: 400px;
      background: red;
      text-align: center;
      letter-spacing: 20px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    document.write('<div class="letter-spacing">'+
                       '<img src="icon1.png">'+
                       '<img src="icon2.png">'+
                   '</div>');
</script>
```

[image]

Is there anybody knows why?

Comment: Strange but the css is applied : http://jsbin.com/gicataduzo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: why cant you try " .letter-spacing img{
      background:red;
      text-align:center;
      margin-right:20px;
    }"  instead of letter spacing.. you can use letter spacing for words, For images try margin-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because you write it like this

```
document.write('<div class="letter-spacing">'+
                   '<img src="icon1.png">'+
                   '<img src="icon2.png">'+
               '</div>');
```

which will resulting in this `HTML`

```
<div class="letter-spacing"><img src="icon1.png"><img src="icon2.png"></div>
```

which doesn't contain any space, thus `letter-spacing: 20px;` not working.

Different with the one you write directly in `HTML` with a `new line` which considered as a space.

If you want to have the same results, then change it to this

```
document.write('<div class="letter-spacing">'+
                   '<img src="icon1.png"> '+    // Note the space before '
                   '<img src="icon2.png">'+
               '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange, but I could fix it in some hard way like this

```
document.write('<div class="letter-spacing"> '+
               '<img style="margin-right: 20px;" src="icon1">'+
                   '<img src="icon2">'+
               '</div>');
```

But if I set a class in css it does not work. Thats really strange